# not all paths return a value in anonymous method

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a method that checks if a number is abundant (the sum of all his proper divisors is greater than the number itself), but I get an error at the `1.ToInc(28123, 1)` line of code which says: "Not all code paths return a value in anonymous method of type `System.Func<int,bool>`". I believe this is referring to my `isAbundant` method. What in `isAbundant` doesn't return a value?

```
public void Solve ()
{
    //Check if number is abundant -> number < sum of proper divisors. memoize this
    Func<int, bool> isAbundant = x =>
    {
        return x < ProperDivisors (x).Select(x => x).Sum () && x >= 0;
    };

        isAbundant = isAbundant.Memoize ();

        //make a sequence of all these numbers for readability
        var seq = 12.ToInc (28123, 1).TakeWhile (x => isAbundant (x));

                    // take all the numbers between 13 and 28123 take while (from 12 to number / 2 from sequence) check if number - item from sequence isn't abundant
        1.ToInc (28123, 1).TakeWhile (x => {
            foreach (var i in seq){
                if (i < x/2){
                    if (isAbundant (x - i))
                        return false;
                    else
                        return true;
                }
            }
        })
        // Sum
        .Sum ().Display ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually referring to your lambda here:

```
.TakeWhile (x => {
        foreach (var i in seq){
            if (i < x/2){
                if (isAbundant (x - i))
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }

        // If there are no elements in seq, you'll reach here, and never return a value!
        // Add something here, ie:
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: @Reapo: to add to Reed-Copsey's correct assessment, I think you're possibly confused over what your `.TakeWhile` statement is trying to do. In the code as you've written it, this code sample loops over `seq` until it finds the first value that satisfies `< x/2`, then returns a true or false statement. If you don't have such a value in `seq`, then it should be obvious that you currently do not end up returning anything.

Comment: thank you for pointing out that I overlooked the fact that the compiler might say that there aren't any values in seq. Added the return value to it. @Andrew, I believe the code does what I want it to, which is, it takes the value x if the function returns true, doesn't take it if it returns false.